# What's the graph concept behind this?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Need to assign a person to another person from a group random manner. Everyone should be assigned to someone. What's the graph concept behind this? I need to write an algorithm for this.

Eg:
-A is assigned to B, B is assigned to C, C is assigned to A (directed graph)
or
-A is assigned to C, B is assigned to A, C is assigned to B

1. A, B, C all three should be assigned to someone.
2. A, B, C all three should have one as assignment.
3. No duplicate assignment.
4. One person should be assigned to only one.
5. One person can be assigned to at least one.

Comment: This isn't a graph problem. It's more a combinatorics one. Although, you haven't given enough information to make sure about it. If you just want every element to be paired with another one you are looking for n/2 disjoint components. This is the closest to a graph problem I can think of.

Comment: First thing to clarify:    If we assign person A to person B, then is B also assigned to A?   If so, it's an undirected graph.  Either way, what you're trying to do is find a *matching*, and you can look this up in Wikipedia.

Comment: It seems like you can order the people any way you want, and then each person is assigned to the person before them (with the first person being assigned to the last). There's not really a concept behind this in any useful sense because the problem as stated is essentially trivial, although you can perhaps if there's additional local constraints of which people can or can't be assigned to others it might be finding a decomposition of a graph into cycles.

Comment: @Meera if there is no other constraint, what you describe is a linked list which points its last entry back to the first one.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut it should be shuffled. Not in the order. But what you said leads another idea. it can be shuffled. And added as cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be expressed as a graph problem if you put it the following way:
There is a source S
There is a pipe of cost N from S to each of your A, B, C .... points
There is a pipe of cost N for each of A,B,C to A',B',C' whenever the choice X => Y is acceptable
There is pipe of cost N for each A',B',C' ... to a sink K

Then finding an acceptable match between A,B,C ... and A',B',C' ... means maximizing from from S to K with a minimal cost O(N3) problem.
By changing the costs of the pipe you can introduce preference and find the optimal choice which minimizes "sum of discontents".